# CMD doesnt redirect me to ":title"

Tags: batch-file

I've got a problem with my batch file. The only option that's working for me is the first `set /p user=`. When i type `1` it will redirect me to `:USERN`. The 2nd, 3rd and 4th options are not working...

For information, if I press `2` it should redirect me to `:USERD` but `cmd` just stays in `Main`

```
:Main
set /p user= 
if %user% == 1 goto USERN
if not %user% == 1 goto Main
set /p user1= 
if %user1% == 2 goto USERD
if not %user1% == 2 goto Main
set /p user2= 
if %user2% == 3 goto OSN
if not %user2% == 3 goto Main
set /p user3= 
if %user3% == 4 goto CPN
if not %user3% == 4 goto Main
pause > nul
:USERN
title Username
cls
echo.
echo the current username was copied into the clipboard
set /p="%username%"<NUL|clip
echo.
echo press 0 to go back
set /p back=
if %back% EQU 0 goto Main
if not %back% EQU 0 goto USERN
pause > nul
:USERD
title UserDomain
cls
echo.
echo the current userdomain was copied into the clipboard
set /p="%userdomain%"<NUL|clip
echo.
echo press 0 to go back
set /p back=
if %back% EQU 0 goto Main
if not %back% EQU 0 goto USERD
:OS
Title Operation System
cls
echo.
echo the name of the Operating System was copied into the clipboard
set /p="%os%"<NUL|clip
echo.
echo pree 0 to go back
set /p back=
if %back% EQU 0 goto Main
if not %back% EQU 0 goto OS
pause > nul
:CDN
Title Computername
cls
echo.
echo the Name of this Computer was copied into the clipboard
set /p="%computername%"<NUL|clip
echo.
echo pree 0 to go back
set /p back=
if %back% EQU 0 goto Main
if not %back% EQU 0 goto CDN
pause > nul
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When `%user%` is not 1, you always go back to `Main`, so you never go after your 4th line (except when inputing 1).

Always test `%user%` variable, replace your `Main` label with this:

```
SET /p user= Prompt:
IF %user% LSS 1 ( GOTO Main )
IF %user% GTR 4 ( GOTO Main )
IF %user% EQU 4 ( GOTO CPN )
IF %user% EQU 3 ( GOTO OSN )
IF %user% EQU 2 ( GOTO USERD )
IF %user% EQU 1 ( GOTO USERN )
```

There, if `%user%` is greater than 4 or lower 1, it will go back to `Main`, otherwise it will go to the proper label.

Comment: You're welcomed! You maybe can accept the answer, this will somewhat close the question, unless you still have some issues about this.